# What does 'Checked out revision 0' mean?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I need to access the source code for a plug-in in a software OpenSim and their instructions say to use an SVN ( https://simtk.org/scm/?group_id=1065 ). I just installed Tortoise SVN to my computer and don't really know what it is doing. In the command prompt, I did as instructed and typed 'svn checkout --username anonsvn https://simtk.org/svn/synergy/'. The output says 'Checked out revision 0'. What does this mean?

I have a Windows 10 64-bit computer. The only steps that I did after learning I needed to use an SVN were downloading SVN 1.11 and adding it to my path, installing TortoiseSVN with the command prompt lines, and then running this line.

'''
Input:
svn checkout --username anonsvn https://simtk.org/svn/synergy/
'''

'''
Output:
Checked out revision 0.
'''

I am not sure what this output means, if I'm doing it completely wrong, or it actually worked and I just don't know where to go from here. Please help.

Comment: 202 downloads and the last update to the project was 3 years ago, according to the project's website. It's unlikely that the developer will properly upload the code into the repository at this point. Consider it abandoned/dead and use something different that's actually being developed. Or, just download the distribution version and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to access the source code for a plug-in

It seems that this project did not publish its source code because the repository is empty.

```
Checked out revision 0.
```

This message means that you've checked out a working copy from the repository that does not have any content. When you create a new repository, it has only one revision 0.

Comment: I think the issue might be I didn't create a repository at first. How can I create one and set it up correctly to allow the source code to go into it?

Comment: @Eric no, the problem is that the project's repository is empty and was never populated by project's maintainer.